# Emulator: no more room on this home screen

Tags: android

something happened to my app as i cannot place the widget in the Emulator. It says: no more room on this home screen. I tried to modifiy the layout_width parameters but nothing have changed. Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:id="@+id/widgetlayout"
    android:background="@drawable/blacktrans"
    >

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="200px"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:id="@+id/widgetlayoutinside3"
        android:paddingTop="3px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
        >
        <TextView android:id="@+id/widget_textview3"
            android:text="widget_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="70px"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:paddingLeft="15px"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
            />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/ButtonP3" 
            android:layout_width="28px" 
            android:layout_height="28px"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/widget_textview3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5px">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ButtonS3" 
            android:layout_width="28px" 
            android:layout_height="28px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ButtonP3">
        </Button>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/ButtonM3" 
            android:layout_width="28px" 
            android:layout_height="28px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ButtonS3">
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try swiping to an empty home-screen on the emulator and putting it there.

Answer (score 0):

If there is too many icon on screen and your widget is so big, you can't place it. I think you must move the icons and make smaller widget.

Comment: jeez why do you think i am so stupid to place a widget in a small space where there is not enough? There is NOTHING on the screen, NOTHING

Comment: LoL, There are a lot people who make this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Read the section about widths for widgets again.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#sizes

I'd suggest using a standard size, and trying to see how that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

widget screen sizes are in 80x100y dip in portrait per cell and 106x74y dip in landscape.   You need to make sure your widget can either statically conform to that size or be dynamically assigned to it (i.e. fill_parent)